# How to add chinese font in jspdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to add Chinese font in jspdf. But its throwing the warning

> "Unable to look up font label for font 'NotoSansCJKjp', 'normal'.
>   Refer to getFontList() for available fonts."
>
> **errors:** jsPDF PubSub Error id is undefined TypeError: "id is
>   undefined"

I tried with below link 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-customfonts#install

```
            doc.addFont('NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.ttf', 'NotoSansCJKjp', 'normal');
            doc.setFont('NotoSansCJKjp');
            doc.text(15, 30, 'こんにちは。はじめまして。');

            //multi-lines Test
            var paragraph = '相次いで廃止された寝台列車に代わり、いまや夜間の移動手段として主力になりつつある夜行バス。「安い」「寝ながら移動できる」などのメリットを生かすため、運行ダイヤはどのように組まれているのでしょうか。夜遅く出て、朝早く着くというメリット夜行バスを使うメリットといえば、各種アンケートでもいちばん多い回答の「安い」以外に、';
            var lines = doc.splitTextToSize(paragraph, 150);
            doc.text(15, 60, lines);
```

Comment: Minor detail but that's actually japanese in your code

Answer (score 0):

I believe to be able to `addFont` you need first to [addFileToVFS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-customfonts#addfiletovfs-method) it.